# How to programmatically update a MatChipList?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following control using `mat-chip-list`. Once the user enters a few chips in the list and data is saved, I need to programmatically replace the chips with new ones (in case that the same keyword/chip is added simultaneously and found in the database but with different casing or accents we want the UI to auto-refresh to match the database).

How can I update the chips possibly using the MatChipList object (`@ViewChild("keywordChipList") keywordChipList: MatChipList;`).

```
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="50" class="mat-form-field-font">
          <mat-label>{{ "APP_KEYWORDS" | translate }}</mat-label>
          <mat-chip-list #keywordChipList>
            <mat-chip
              *ngFor="let keyword of keywordList"
              [selectable]="true"
              [removable]="true"
              (removed)="removeKeyword(keyword)"
            >
              {{ keyword.text }}
              <fa-icon
                *ngIf="!keywordCtrl.disabled"
                matChipRemove
                icon="times-circle"
              ></fa-icon>
            </mat-chip>
            <input
              placeholder=""
              #keywordInput
              #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger"
              [formControl]="keywordCtrl"
              [matAutocomplete]="keywordAutocomplete"
              [matChipInputFor]="keywordChipList"
              [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
              [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
              (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addKeyword($event)"
              (focus)="getKeywordCollection()"
            />
          </mat-chip-list>
          <mat-autocomplete
            #keywordAutocomplete="matAutocomplete"
            (optionSelected)="keywordSelected($event)"
          >
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let keyword of keywordFilteredItems$ | async"
              [value]="keyword"
            >
              {{ keyword.text }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Before/After visual sample

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Basically, the "After" shows Canada with an uppercase 'C' because some other user had entered Canada in the database (just a few seconds before while the user was in the process of entering the same keyword but with lower case)... the application finds (case-insensitive) in the database and automatically should update the chip which the case-insensitive match.

Comment: can you provide sample mat-chip-list ? how it would look before and how it should be?

Comment: Thanks, @PavithraMuthusamy. Just updated with some screenshots